# Writing a VBA function to sum "Cost Per Hour" into "Cost Per Day" and then into "Cost per Month"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to model the cost of my home heating unit. I have 3.15 years of hourly data. I calculated cost per hour, cost per day, cost per month, and cost per year. I want to write two VBA function, one called `CostPerDay` and the other called `CostPerMonth` in order to simplify the process when I add more data. I have attached a picture of my data.

Picture of Data

[image]

The function I wrote for Cost Per Day is:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($M$18,(ROW()-18)*24,0,24,1))
```

The function I wrote for Cost Per Month is:

```
Jan-13 =SUM(OFFSET($P$18,(ROW()-18)*31,0,31,1))
Feb-13 =SUM(OFFSET($P$49,(ROW()-19)*28,0,28,1))
Mar-13 =SUM(OFFSET($P$77,(ROW()-20)*31,0,31,1))
Etc...
```

In case you need the whole range of data:

```
Cost Per Hour - M18:M27636
Cost Per Day - P18:P1168
Cost Per Month - S18:S55
Average Cost Per Month - V18:V29
```

This is what I was trying. As you can see, I am new to VBA. In the first attempt, I was trying to use Dim to define where the data was located in the spreadsheet and which cell I wanted the calculation in. I got stuck because I couldn't insert the `=SUM(OFFSET($M$18,(ROW()-18)*24,0,24,1))`function into VBA. I then was trying to make get rid of the hard-coded `$M$18`by replacing it with `Cells(Match(Day,O18:O1168)+17,"P")`. But none of it worked.

The second one I was playing with dialogue boxes, but I don't think I want to use them.

In the third attempt I was trying to calculate Cost Per Month. I don't have it because I didn't save it. I was using `SUMIFS`to match Months with the number of days in the month. That may have been my closest attempt but it still didn't work.

```
Function CostPerDay(BeginningCostPerDay, OutputCell)
    Dim BeginningCostPerDay, OutputCell
        BeginningCostPerDay = WorksheetFunction.DSum()
        OutputCell = ActiveCell.Offset(3, -3).Activate
End Function

Function CostPerDay1()
    Dim myValue1 As Variant, myValue2 As Variant
        myValue1 = InputBox("Where do you want the data put?")
        myValue2 = InputBox("What is the beginning Cost Per Day")
            Range("myValue1").Value = myValue1
            Range("myValue2").Value = myValue2

End Function
```

Comment: Why not [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B)? [AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690)?

Comment: How would I sum every 24 cells using SUMIFS for Cost per Day?

Comment: `=SUM(INDEX(M:M, (ROW(1:1)-1)*24+18):INDEX(M:M, (ROW(1:1)-1)*24+41))` uses the non-volatile [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) instead of the volatile [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592).

Comment: Thank you! How would I write a function in VBA? Preferably, I dont want to hard-code anything.

Comment: You tap [alt]+F11 and start typing. People asking for code are **expected** to show original effort. We are here to help you get through problems you encounter; not write your code for you.

Comment: How do I format the code like you have? If I copy and paste it, it will post in a block text format.

Comment: Don't post code blocks into comments. Edit your question and include it as an update. once you have it there, select it and tap [ctrl]+K.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Writing%20a%20VBA%20function%20to%20sum%20Cost%20Per%20Hour%20into%20Cost%20Per%20Day%20and%20then%20into%20Cost%20per%20Month.xlsx). I honestly doubt whether you are going to increase worksheet efficiency very much past those optimized formulas, VBA or no VBA.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to make that spreadsheet! My hope was to simply create a user defined function so that someone else (who has little excel experience) can easily update my spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I am wondering whether you can explain where the 41 comes from in =SUM(INDEX(M:M, (ROW(1:1)-1)*24+18):INDEX(M:M, (ROW(1:1)-1)*24+41))

Answer (score 0):

What if you added a helper column that started with 1 in cell A1 for example.  Second row (A2) would be =If(A1=24,1,A1+1). Column B would have the hourly data. Column C or C1 would say =If(and(A1=24,A2=1),B1,B1+B2)). I didn't test, but I think this should work with perhaps a tweak.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer.

```
Private Sub SumCosts(ByVal MainColumn As String, ByVal CostColumn As String, ByVal FirstDataRow As Long, Optional ByVal BracketType As Byte)
  '
  'Parameters:
  'MainColumn: the columns with dates or months.
  'CostColumn: the column that holds the costs to sum.
  'FirstDataRow: the first row where the data starts
  'BracketType: either 0 for hours or 1 for months
  '
  'This procedure assumes that in the data on the sheet
  '- every hour of every day in the hours columns
  '- every day of a month is present in the days columns
  'are present. I.e. All hours of all 31 days of January are persent
  'in the 'Date' column before the hours of February start and all days of January
  'are present in the 'Month' column before the days of February start.
  Const Hours As Byte = 24
  '
  Dim Cel As Range
  Dim I As Long
  Dim J As Long
  Dim K As Long
  Dim Rng As String
  Dim Bracket As Byte
  Dim Days As Byte
  '
  'Clean the target area, so the modle can be reused time after time.
  Set Cel = Range(MainColumn & Application.Rows.Count).Offset(0, 1)
  Rng = Split(Cel.Address, "$")(1)
  Rng = (Rng & FirstDataRow & ":" & Rng & Cel.End(xlUp).Row)
  Range(Rng).ClearContents
  '
  J = FirstDataRow
  For Each Cel In Range(MainColumn & ":" & MainColumn)
    If Cel.Value = vbNullString Then Exit For
    If Cel.Row > (FirstDataRow - 1) Then
      'Number of days in a month. Since this fluctuates the bracket fluctuates.
      Days = DateSerial(Year(Cel.Value), Month(Cel.Value) + 1, 1) - DateSerial(Year(Cel.Value), Month(Cel.Value), 1)
      Bracket = IIf(BracketType = 0, Hours, Days)  'Select the bracket to use.
      K = ((Cel.Row - 1) * Bracket) + (FirstDataRow - 1)  'Determine where to stop calculating for a given day or month.
      For I = J To K
        Cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cel.Offset(0, 1).Value + Range(CostColumn & I).Value  'Do the calculation.
      Next
      J = K + 1  'Next loop we must pick up where we left off.
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Public Sub LaunchCostCalculations()
  SumCosts "O", "M", 2, 0
  SumCosts "R", "P", 2, 1
End Sub
```

Create a button in your sheet to launch LaunchCostCalculations and Bob's your uncle.